# Using Tweepy to Get Public Metrics

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to append like count and favorite count to a tweepy query I have written. I have the correct auth and get the tweet information just fine. I am using API v2. The docs for how this information should be received is [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet).

The query I am using to pull the tweets is

```
def get_relevant_tweets(tweets: List) -> pd.DataFrame:

    relevant_tweets = []
    created_at = []
    metrics = []

    for tweet in tqdm(tweets):

        if len(tweet.context_annotations) <= 0:

            pass

        else:

            for context_annotation in tweet.context_annotations:

                if "entity" in context_annotation:

                    if context_annotation["entity"]["name"].lower() in [
                        "nfl",
                        "nfl football",
                        "gambling",
                        "american football",
                        "Sports betting",
                    ]:

                        relevant_tweets = relevant_tweets + [tweet.text]
                        created_at = created_at + [tweet.created_at]

                        public_metrics = tweet.public_metrics

                        metrics = metrics + [public_metrics] 

    df = pd.DataFrame(relevant_tweets)

    df.columns = ["tweet"]

    df["created_at"] = created_at

    df['metrics'] = metrics

    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

    return df
```

However, this returns null for the public_metrics every time. Am I missing something?